# Branch model for multiple projects in the same repository?

Tags: git, workflow, git-branch, git-flow

We've recently switched from CVS to Git and are using Vincent Driessen's [successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) with a `master` branch and a `develop` branch which merges back to `master`. We started with one project in Git and now we have two separate projects using some common code in a submodule (`common`). Recently the other project committed a change to `develop` that we aren't prepared for, and until we've updated our own code, we cannot commit any changes back to `develop` because we don't want the other changes.

I thought about branching `develop` into project-specific branches which merge back into `develop`, but the owner of `common` doesn't want project-specific branches because:

> we’ll have to cherry pick commits from the main `develop` branch in
>   order to obtain fixes or features that apply to both.

Would it be better to eliminate the `develop` branch entirely and just merge directly from project-specific branches back to `master`, or are we doing this all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Recently the other project committed a change to develop that we aren't prepared for, and until we've updated our own code, we cannot commit any changes back to develop because we don't want the other changes.

That means the two projects have different development life-cycles, and should have each their own develop branch.
But if `common` cannot updated easily by both projects, that means you have to update `common` yourself (in a project-specific branch of its own)

Before merging your `develop` branch to the main official `develop` one, you will need to merge `common` from the main `develop` branch to your version of `common`, resolve any conflict, and merge back `common` as well.
That way, the `common` project owner won't have to cherry-pick or integrate anything.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!